# $m$ distinct boxes and $n$ distinct balls probability problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, balls-in-bins

I have looked at similar questions, however I could not find an answer to my specific problem. The problem is the following: If I have $m$ distinct boxes and $n$ distinct balls, what is the probability of finding all the balls in the same box.

I thought that I can do this via $\frac{number of successes}{number of arrangements}$, where the number of arrangements should be $m^n$?

Comment: Rare probability/combinatorics problem that is more easily solved by probability than combinatorics.  All balls must go in the same box as ball-1.  Each ball's placement is an independent event.  What is the probability that ball-2 goes in the same box as ball-1?  To answer this question, you can assume, without loss of generality, that ball-1 went into box-1.

Comment: So, if ball 1 went into box1, then all the others including ball 2 HAVE to go into box 1 as well. The probability of, say ball 2, going into box 1 is then $\frac{1}{m}$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Hmm I am stuck. So the probability of ball2 going into the same box is $\frac{1}{m}$, but so is the probability for all other balls. Wouldn't that amount to $(\frac{1}{m})^n$ ?

Comment: No, you want $~\left( ~\dfrac{1}{m} ~\right)^{[n-1]},~$ since it does not matter which box that ball-1 goes into.  All that is necessary is that balls 2 through n *follow* ball-1 into whatever box that ball-1 goes into.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the outcomes are equally likely (balls are distinct), the answer can be obtained as follows by counting:

$$ \frac{ \binom{m}{1} \times 1^n}{m^n}=\frac{1}{m^{n-1}}$$

Note that if the balls are not distinct, the counting method cannot be used. Instead, the following method can be used for both cases:

$$ \binom{m}{1} 
\left ( \frac{1}{m} \right) ^n=\frac{1}{m^{n-1}}.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, appreciate it!

Comment: You are very welcome! If you think the solution is complete, you can accept it, which makes your question more visible.

Answer (score 0):

We can calculate the probability that all the balls go in a marked box the probability of that happening is (1/M)^N the marked box can be chosen in M ways so the answer is M * (1/M)^N .

Comment: Thanks for your help!